# Pushing a new repository with HgWebDir via http

Tags: mercurial

I have successfully set up an HgWebDir instance over CGI with Apache, and I can `hg push` and `hg pull` to all the repositories listed on the page, but I cannot create a new repository without ssh and such as it gives me ann "Operation not supported via http" error.

Is that a configuration error or it's really not supported? Has anyone ever succeeded on doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can't create a new repo over HTTP with the standard tools.  You **can** push-create using ssh, but hgwebdir doesn't do that.  You can `hg init` up an empty repo on the server and then push to it, though.

It's easy to set up a separate script to do the remote creation over http: http://ry4an.org/unblog/UnBlog/2009-09-17

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported as far as I know. That would be a security problem if you think about it. hgwebdir has no security model to speak of, I would think that creating directories and files on the server would require some sort credentials.